# Will the garbage collector free this List when my method finishes running

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Lets say I have something like:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Code;
    public List<string> Codes = new List<string>();
}

private void SomeMethod()
{
    List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Item NewItem = new Item();
        NewItem.Code = "Something " + i.ToString();
        NewItem.Codes.Add("Something " + i.ToString());
        Items.Add(Item);
    }

    //Do something with Items
}
```

I am instantiating Item and not free'ing it because I need to have access to it in the list later on (rough example).

What I am wondering is when `SomeMethod()` has finished executing, will Items (and the contents of it - including the List<>) be de-referenced and allow the garbage collector to clean up the memory as and when it runs? Basically, will this section of code cause any memory leaks or should everything be de-referenced when `SomeMethod()` has finished processing.

My understanding is that when nothing holds a reference to an object it will be garbage collected so in my mind this code should be Ok but I just wanted to make sure I understand correctly.

EDIT:

If I was to add one of the objects `Items` is holding into another list that would still be in scope (a global list for example). What would happen?

Comment: Think about it for a second:  *can* you delete an object yourself?  (Nope.)  So doesn't the runtime pretty much *have* to delete it for you?  No ability to do something == no responsibility on your part to do it either.

Comment: @webnoob, since that object would still be referenced it would not be released/collected, the rest of the list object and its other members would be.

Comment: Many thanks. I don't want to design areas of my application on an assumption if they are not correct :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once your variable `Items` goes out of scope, the garbage collector will indeed dispose of it (and its contents, as your code is written) at its leisure.

Comment: Ok thanks, could you clarify something else for me then please. If I was to add one of the objects `Items` is holding into another list that would still be in scope. What would happen?

Comment: @webnoob only the "out of scope"/deferenced items get collected. So, the rest of the object graph would get released but the memory for the referenced object would not.

Comment: Ok great, I assume it would then be collected once the global list was free'd?

Comment: @webnoob - Then that object would still be around, but the rest would go away.  For almost every scenario, you can assume that if you can't access it any more, than the garbage collector has disposed of it.  Unless it opens external resources, in which case it should implement `IDisposable` and you should use it in a `using` statement.

Comment: I use `using ()` on anything that implements `IDisposable` and have implemented the interface on a few of my own classes, I just get a little confused with the ones that don't implement it. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @webnoob, of course. The garbage collector would release/collect the memory at some point after it went out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

The garbage collector will collect anything that is no longer reachable by code. Since you will no longer be able to reach your Items list or any of the Items contained within the list, then the garbage collector will collect them at some point. Your understanding of the garbage collector is correct.

Comment: The list that is still in-scope would be retained, but the Item that was referencing it would be collected since you couldn't reach the Item from code without a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

```
List<Item> Items
```

is declared in the scope of the method. So when the method ends, it goes out of scope and is the list is dereferenced.

The memory will be released at some point after that, when the Garbage Collecter sees fit.

---

As an aside, since `Items` is declared in a "local" scope I'd prefer to call it `items`.

Comment: It's an OCD thing. I have always used `ThisIsMyVar` casing and it's stuck. I attach `F` to class scope vars so `FThisIsMyVar`. Old habbits ..

Comment: Try to break them and stick with accepted conventions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002(v=vs.100).aspx - you'll make things so much easier for others when you're long gone... Make "correct" your new OCD thing!

Comment: @tomfanning, I don't want to dwell on style but your link doesent cover the naming of private variables, only the public interfaces of classes. Variables should be named with CamelCase like parameter names. If you use PascalCase it doesent't distinguish them from public class members and properties, and may lead to confusion in abstract scenarios, like here. I use Style Cop in combination with Resharper to make me follow the prevailing conventions but that is probably because I'm a wanna be pedant. http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1306.html

Comment: Oh, and "OCD" should be "Ocd" :-p

Comment: No it shouldn't; it's an acronym.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep things sane and keep its job, GC has to promise two things:

1. **Garbage will be collected.**  This seems pretty obvious, but if the GC doesn't promise to clean up managed objects without you having to tell it to, it's rather useless.
2. ***ONLY*** garbage will be collected.  You don't have to worry about the GC cleaning up objects that are still in play.

So, once `Items` goes out of scope (that is, once the function returns), it's no longer reachable by running code, so it's eligible for collection without you having to do anything.  Since the items in the list are no longer reachable either (their only link was in the list), they're eligible too.  If you returned a reference to an entry in the list, though, that object is still in play and can't be collected yet.  GC will do the right thing.

In fact, GC *almost always* does the right thing.  There are really only three major cases you have to worry about:

- **If you're buiding a container** (like if you're making your own `List` workalike). Any objects that no longer "exist" in the container as far as the user is concerned, should generally be set to null so the GC doesn't see them as reachable through your collection and erroneously keep them alive.  If you remove an item from the collection, for example, null out the reference or overwrite it with another.
- **With large (>~85KB?) objects**.  They'll typically stick around in memory til they crowd out everything else, at which point a full GC cycle runs.  (Normally, only certain likely-to-be-discarded objects are checked during a cycle.  Full collections check pretty much *everything*, which takes significantly longer but might free more memory.)
- **If you're using IDisposable objects or native/unmanaged resources.** Some incompetents don't know how to implement IDisposable correctly.  If you're dealing with a library created by such an incompetent, then you'll need to ensure that you `Dispose` stuff, or only ever use it within a `using` block, or things can get really weird.  (If you only use the .net API, you're pretty safe.  But disposing is still good manners.)

For pretty much all other occasions, GC just works.  Trust it.

Answer (score 1):

1. all the variables in the method are in a stackframe and all these variable will be destoried along with the stackframe after the method was executed. 
   that is said after SomeMethod() executed, the variable Items will nolonger exists, thus new List() will be marked "can be collected".
2. the second question is that,  there is a globle list variable hold the reference of one of the object that in the variable Items, then after the SomeMethod() executed, the List in the SomeMethod will be marked as "can be collected", and all the other object beside the item that was referenced by the globle list variable will also be makred as "can be collected"
   the reason is, the list actually hold the reference that point to the exact object in the heap
   So the shared object can not be collected due to the reason that it is referenced by the globleList